# Is there an R package which can modify an existing PDF file?

Tags: r, file, pdf, data-manipulation

I need a package that can convert or give me all of the information contained on a pdf file and that later I can produce a new pdf file with some of that information being changed.
`pdftools` can give me a lot of the information, but I was not able to generate a new pdf from the information being extracted and then modified by me.

My father in his job need to fill some forms that are created by the local Fire Department, so they are often similar but kind of hardworking to modify just by using Adobe Acrobat or Microsoft Word. A package in which I could obtain the data of the pdf, change some of the strings and numbers, and then generate a new pdf with the modified information but same set of fonts, tables, titles, line spacing and everyhting else related to the metadata of the pdf file being the same would be really handy.

I looked some packages that can manipulate pdf files, like `pdftools` and `staplr`, but I wasn't able to generate a new pdf file with the altered information.

Comment: Please see this package. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/staplr/staplr.pdf